# I am using a formula in a spreadsheet and want to reverse it.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am using a formula in a spreadsheet and want to reverse it. I would like to enter a number in one cell and get the result.  Currently I need to insert numbers for $A$ to get the result $B$. Instead, I would like to insert a number for $B$ to get result $A$.
This is the current  formula:

$$A-(0.1A)-(0.029A)-0.035=B$$

How can I reverse this without knowing the value of $A$?

Comment: $A=(B+.035)/(1-0.1-0.029)$

Comment: Hint: $A=1.0A$, then use the distributive property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I interpret your question, we want to solve $A-.1A-.029A-.35=B$ for $B$ in terms of $A$.

If this is incorrect, please tell me.

Proceeding, we collect all of the $A$ terms and add the constant $.035$ to both sides:

$(1-.1-.029)A=.871A=B+.35$

Now, we divide by $.871$ on both sides:

$$A=\frac{B+.35}{.871}$$

EDIT: It's also worth noting that $A-.1A-.029A-.035=.871A-.35=B$

EDIT 2: changed for comment

Comment: I made and error. The .035 should have been .35 instead. I was able to use your method to solve the problem. Thank you for your help.

"_I love math! I'm just not very good at it_." -Thomas John